# Nutch 1.14 ant failed

Tags: java, ant, ivy, nutch

I have a problem with nutch 1.14 & ant

My Java version

> java version "1.8.0_141"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)

My ant version

> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017

So, I have download nutch1.14-src and I configured nutch as proposed on this site http://techsphot.unaux.com/installig-nutch-1-14-on-ubuntu/

Finally when i execute `ant runtime` I have a problem with ivy2::resolve

It's possible to build nutch without ivy ?

The `ant runtime` output

```
[ivy:resolve]    trying /root/.ivy2/local/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/jars/slf4j-api.jar
[ivy:resolve]       tried /root/.ivy2/local/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/jars/slf4j-api.jar
[ivy:resolve]   local: resource not reachable for org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: res=/root/.ivy2/local/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/jars/slf4j-api.jar
[ivy:resolve]   local: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1
[ivy:resolve]   no ivy file in cache for org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: tried /root/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/ivy-1.6.1.xml
[ivy:resolve]    trying http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]       tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom
Finding class org.apache.ivy.util.url.IvyAuthenticator
Loaded from /opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/ivy/ivy-2.4.0.jar org/apache/ivy/util/url/IvyAuthenticator.class
Class java.net.Authenticator loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.ivy.util.url.IvyAuthenticator loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.apache.ivy.util.Credentials
Loaded from /opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/ivy/ivy-2.4.0.jar org/apache/ivy/util/Credentials.class
Class org.apache.ivy.util.Credentials loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.SecurityException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
[ivy:resolve] ERROR: Server access error at url http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))
Class java.io.PrintWriter loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
[ivy:resolve] java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.checkStatusCode(BasicURLHandler.java:131)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.getURLInfo(BasicURLHandler.java:73)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.getURLInfo(BasicURLHandler.java:54)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.util.url.URLHandlerDispatcher.getURLInfo(URLHandlerDispatcher.java:66)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLResource.init(URLResource.java:68)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLResource.exists(URLResource.java:84)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.findResourceUsingPattern(RepositoryResolver.java:97)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.findResourceUsingPatterns(AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.java:97)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.findIvyFileRef(IBiblioResolver.java:103)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:230)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.getDependency(IBiblioResolver.java:506)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.getDependency(ChainResolver.java:104)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:170)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:718)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:803)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:726)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:791)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:726)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:599)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:236)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:197)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.resolve(Ivy.java:508)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyResolve.doExecute(IvyResolve.java:330)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:271)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ivy:resolve]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ivy:resolve]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
[ivy:resolve]   at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
[ivy:resolve]   maven2: resource not reachable for org/slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: res=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]    trying http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
[ivy:resolve]       tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
```

**EDIT :**
After downloading the dependency on failure I have a strange `ivy::resolve`.
It is looking for a resource with my hostname and so can not solve this one

```
Finding class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver$3
Loaded from /opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/ivy/ivy-2.4.0.jar org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/BasicResolver$3.class
Class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver$3 loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
[ivy:resolve]    trying /root/.ivy2/local/org.apache/hello-ivy/working@MYHOSTNAME/jars/hello-ivy.jar
[ivy:resolve]       tried /root/.ivy2/local/org.apache/hello-ivy/working@MYHOSTNAME/jars/hello-ivy.jar
[ivy:resolve]   local: resource not reachable for org.apache#hello-ivy;working@MYHOSTNAME: res=/root/.ivy2/local/org.apache/hello-ivy/working@MYHOSTNAME/jars/hello-ivy.jar
[ivy:resolve]    trying http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hello-ivy/working@MYHOSTNAME/hello-ivy-working@MYHOSTNAME.jar
[ivy:resolve]       tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hello-ivy/working@MYHOSTNAME/hello-ivy-working@MYHOSTNAME.jar
Finding class org.apache.ivy.util.url.IvyAuthenticator
Loaded from /opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/ivy/ivy-2.4.0.jar org/apache/ivy/util/url/IvyAuthenticator.class
Class java.net.Authenticator loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.ivy.util.url.IvyAuthenticator loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.apache.ivy.util.Credentials
Loaded from /opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/ivy/ivy-2.4.0.jar org/apache/ivy/util/Credentials.class
Class org.apache.ivy.util.Credentials loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.SecurityException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
```

Comment: The first error is obviously a connection timeout while downloading a dependency. Why are you running the build as root?

Comment: Thanks, Yes first is a connection timeout but it's strange because a wget to the address works correctly. So i have download one by one dependency.
which user are best to start the execution? I test with root and with user solr for the same result